# jQuery gallery doesn't work in IE.. but DOES after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jquery [galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');
    $('#galleria').galleria({
        image_crop: true,
        /*transition: 'fade',*/
        data_config: function(img) {
            return {
                description: $(img).next('p').html()
            };
        },
        extend: function() {
            this.play(6000); // will advance every 4th second
        }
    });
});
```

It works as expected in Chrome, there is a small flicker on load in Firefox. But in IE its like the code above never gets called. the images are laid out as they would be if I never called the code above. However, simply refreshing and IE will then start working right.

Any ideas what might cause this to happen?

Comment: This is a pretty complex issue ( for ones not familiar with the plugin ), can you provide a link to a demo?

Comment: @meder the word galleria above is a link to the plugin site.. here is a link to where my problem is happening http://www.kranichs.com/johncarder/gallery2

Comment: I see the message `LOG: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector` which might be causing something to break?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing in? Completely doesn't work in IE6, does work in IE7.

Comment: I am testing with ie8, and ie8 compatibility mode.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with IE8 not having all the images ready for you when jQuery fires the DOM ready event.  What happens if you change how you invoke galleria to the same method they use on the plugin site (i.e. `<script>` tags at the bottom of the markup)?

Comment: @Pat thanks for the idea, I made that change, it doesn't seem to have an effect.